# How can I access a state hook value from a callback passed to a listener?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, window-resize

I have a component that needs to listen to window resize, and hide/show sidebar appropriately.
I decided to create a custom hook for this purpose, and it doesn't seem to work properly.

The main problem is that the `mainSidebar` value is always constant, and the update is not being read properly.

This is the hook itself:

```
export function useResizeListener(cb: (this: Window, e: UIEvent) => any) {
    const [size, setSize] = React.useState({ width: window.outerWidth, height: window.outerHeight })

    React.useEffect(() => {
        function _wrapped(this: Window, e: UIEvent): any {
            console.debug('setting size and calling callback', { width: this.outerWidth, height: this.outerHeight })
            setSize({ width: this.outerWidth, height: this.outerHeight })
            cb.call(this, e)
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', _wrapped)
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', _wrapped)
    }, [size.width, size.height])
}
```

And this is the component using it:

```
const shouldHaveSidebar = () => document.body.clientWidth >= ScreenSizes.Tablet

const HomePage: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = (props) => {
    const [mainSidebar, toggleMainSidebar] = React.useState(shouldHaveSidebar())

    useResizeListener(() => {
        console.debug('device width vs tablet width:', document.body.clientWidth, '>=', ScreenSizes.Tablet)
        console.debug('shouldHaveSidebar vs mainSidebar', shouldHaveSidebar(), '!==', mainSidebar)
        if (shouldHaveSidebar() !== mainSidebar) {
            console.debug('setting to', shouldHaveSidebar())
            toggleMainSidebar(shouldHaveSidebar())
        }
    })
    return ...
}
```

Upon toggling viewport size on the Chrome dev inspector device modes, I get this output in the console. Note I started with desktop and then changed to mobile L.

```
setting size and calling callback {width: 1680, height: 1027}
device width vs tablet width: 1146 >= 800
shouldHaveSidebar vs mainSidebar true !== false
setting to true

setting size and calling callback {width: 425, height: 779}
device width vs tablet width: 425 >= 800
shouldHaveSidebar vs mainSidebar false !== false // <--- should be: false !== true
```

1. I tried moving the `_wrapper` function between outside and inside the `useEffect` hook
2. I tried wrapping the callback in a setTimeout/setImmediate
3. I tried wrapping the state get (mainSidebar bool) with a function to retrieve it which is defined in the component and outside the hook call

Neither of these worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mind posting a demo?

Comment: Yes, give me a few minutes. :)

Comment: Here's my take: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-stonebraker-nsktm?file=/src/App.js (basically Ján's approach)

Comment: I had trouble reproducing the problem with a code sandbox, mostly because i couldn't easily resize viewports. But it seems @Jàn's answer will work better than my approach.

Comment: With your apporach problem is [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/), What happened in your case it captures initial value of mainSidebar and never changed during component life. An efficient way to solve stale closures is to correctly set the dependencies of React hooks.

Comment: There are several things there that contribute:

1. In your `useResizeListener` you are not listing `cb` as a dependency. This means that if your `cb` changes `_wrapped` will still be using an old reference which still sees the old `mainSidebar`
2. In your `useResizeListener` you use `size.width` and `size.height` as your `useEffect` dependencies. This means the event handler will get reattached every time it is called and when it is called it will call the `cb` that was passed when the size changed. Also it is a performance hit since you are reattaching the listener for not reason.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. I think it's a mix of what JánJakubNaništa and giorgim said. Jan's answer ended up helping me and worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest restructuring the solution. First I would change the `useResizeListener` into a hook that gives you the window size:

```
export function useWindowSize() {
  const [size, setSize] = React.useState({ width: window.clientWidth, height: window.clientHeight });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize(e: UIEvent) {
      setSize({ width: window.clientWidth, height: window.clientHeight });
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  return size;
}
```

Then in your `HomePage` component:

```
const shouldHaveSidebar = (size) => size.width >= ScreenSizes.Tablet

const HomePage: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = (props) => {
  const size = useWindowSize();
  const mainSidebar = shouldHaveSidebar(size);

  // Now if you want to perform an action when the size changes you cna simply do:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Perform your action here
  }, [size.width, size.height]);

  // ...
}
```